# Qt 4 update to Qt 5 .1

Tags: apt, updates

I have Qt Creator 4. I'm wanting to update it to Qt 5.1 on Ubuntu 13.10. Is there a simple way to do this in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices and both are from terminal.
1. If it's available then

```
   sudo apt-get install qt5.1
```

Will install it from terminal.

1. Wait until Ubuntu prepare & stream it into all Ubuntu 13.10.pretty official release.you will upgrade & bug reporting facility as usual with automatic alternative configuration.
2. Get the source and compile& build to install.

No direct upgrade facility.
No automatic alternate configuration facility.
No bug reporting too.

Choose wise.
Choice is yours

Comment: What do you mean "Updated for future".